# Has a state official ever been impeached twice?

Tags: united-states, impeachment

The Wikipedia article for [Donald Trump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump) states that he is

> the only federal officeholder to be impeached twice.

What about officeholders in *other* jurisdictions of the United States?  **Has any state, territorial, or local official ever been impeached more than once?**

Comment: @CGCampbell, having skimmed the article and doing searches for "twice" & other terms, I fail to see how that would be a complete list. It only mentions Harrison Reed once and Henry Johnston not at all, from Panda's answer. Normally, Wikipedia is a pretty good resource, but this time it's not comprehensive.

Comment: @CGCampbell, so again, how does that one article answer the question? So Johnston was listed, but still only listed once, with conflicting ideas of what impeachment means between different people's research, so that still doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There have been 2 governors who were impeached twice.

From [this Research Response <sup>1</sup> published by the Illinois General Assembly](https://www.ilga.gov/commission/lru/24.U.S.GovImpeachments.pdf), Governors Henry Johnston of Oklahoma and Harrison Reed of Florida were both impeached twice.

Johnston was acquitted in 1928 but convicted in 1929 while Reed was acquitted both times in 1868 and in 1872.

<sup>1</sup>This document was published in July 2008.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, according to the [Brennan Center](https://www.brennancenter.org/our-work/analysis-opinion/what-rod-blagojevichs-double-impeachment-could-mean-trump), Rod Blagojevich, Governor of Illinois from 2003 to 2009, was technically impeached twice in quick succession.

On January 9th, 2009, the Illinois House [voted 114-1](https://www.ilga.gov/legislation/BillStatus.asp?DocNum=1671&GAID=9&DocTypeID=HR&LegId=40049&SessionID=51&GA=95) in a lame-duck session of the 95th General Assembly to impeach Blagojevich for various corruption and abuse of power offences - [thirteen articles of impeachment](http://www.ilga.gov/legislation/fulltext.asp?DocName=&SessionId=51&GA=95&DocTypeId=HR&DocNum=1671&GAID=9&LegID=40049&SpecSess=&Session=) in total.

Just five days later, on the 14th, the newly-sworn-in House of the 96th General Assembly [voted again to impeach](https://www.ilga.gov/legislation/BillStatus.asp?DocNum=5&GAID=10&DocTypeID=HR&LegId=40223&SessionID=76&GA=96), for the same articles, this time succeeding 117-1.

However, although Blagojevich was impeached twice, there was only one trial in the Illinois Senate. Blagojevich was both convicted and barred from holding a state public office again by unanimous vote.

Comment: Why did they have to do this twice? Did the first vote expire because of the session change? If most of the legislators were reelected, it's not surprising that they voted the same way a few days apart -- they're basically just reaffirming the first impeachment.

Comment: @Barmar as far as I understand it, they didn't *have to* re-impeach - the article mentions that it was done out of "an abundance of caution", and "neutralizing any argument that the lame duck impeachment was ineffective".